# ajax can't going into success method

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, ajax, spring

here is controller:

```
@ResponseBody
@PostMapping("/signup")
public String signUp(HttpServletRequest request) {
    try {
        log.info("-------signup page");
    String username = request.getParameter(Constant.PARAMETER_USERNAME);
    if (userDetailService.findByUsername(username)!=null) {
        log.error("----------username is exist!!");
        return Constant.MESS_EXIST_USER;
    }
    log.info("----------username is not exist!!");
    User user = new User();
    user.setUsername(username);
    user.setPassword(passwordEncoder.encode(request.getParameter(Constant.PARAMETER_PASSWORD)));
    user.setEmail(request.getParameter(Constant.PARAMETER_EMAIL));
    user.setPhonenumber(request.getParameter(Constant.PARAMETER_PHONE)) ;
    user.setAddress(request.getParameter(Constant.PARAMETER_ADDRESS));
    user.setFullname(request.getParameter(Constant.PARAMETER_FULLNAME));
    String status = userService.save(user);
    log.info(status );
    return status;// return "success" or "fail"
    }
    }catch (Exception e) {
        log.error("sign up has been error: ",e);
        return Constant.MESS_FAIL; // "fail"
    }
}
```

and js:

```
var data = $('form#form1').serialize();
    $.ajax({
        url: '/signup',
        data: data,
        type: "POST",
        datatype : "text",
        success: function(data){
            console.log(data);
            if(data == "success"){
                alert("signup success!");
                window.location.href = "/index";

            }else if(data=="existUser"){
                alert("username is exist!");
                window.location.href = "/index";
            }
            else if(data=="fail"){
                alert("signup fail!");
                window.location.href = "/index";
            }

        }
    });
}
```

log of save(user) is success but ajax not alert("signup success!"), it show error page. When I debug in js and java, ajax worked and show alert("signup success!"). I try search in google but it can't run. Anyone help me :(

EDIT
I try use datatype = 'text' and not dublicate save(user). When I run it then seem it not going into success function but when i debug in js then my program is running normally :(

Comment: try promises, like for example `.then(function(data){ console.log(data)}`. bind it to actual ajax call just after.

Comment: You're saving your user twice, you sure you're not getting errors due to that?

Comment: @seethrough why would that fire if `success` won't?

Comment: Inspect the actual request in browser dev tools network. What is `status`. Is what is sent and received as expected? Don't see any json being sent from server side code but that is what you are requesting in `dataType`

Comment: `datatype : "JSON"` ... `datatype` sets *The type of data that you're expecting back from the server* - why would you expect `data` to be the string "success"? That's not JSON

Comment: also, if your client side code is being called as the result of a **submit** - you'll need to prevent the default form submit action

Comment: just to remove some confusion, can you rename the parameter of success function to something other than data. you already have an variable at the beginning named as data.

Comment: Hi all, I try use datatype = 'text' and not dublicate save(user). When I run it then seem it not going into success function but when i debug in js then my program is running normally :(

Comment: @seethrough: i try it but it show log is "success " when I debug in js and not show when I start program.